# How to expand the sum of a squared bracket?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I am following the video lecture series "Bayesian Statistics: Techniques and Models" - week 1 lesson 2: Non-conjugate models from UCSC and am having trouble understanding how they expanded their summation of a squared bracket, as I haven't seen the theory for this before. (I have omitted parts of the equation that are not relevant but still visible in the provided attachment.)
[The formula in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm9Hn.png)

$$-1/2\sum_{i=1}^n (yi-\mu)^2$$

turns into

$$-1/2(\sum_{i=1}^n yi^2-2\mu \sum_{i=1}^n yi + n\mu^2)$$

Would someone be able to walk through the process of expansion between these two steps or provide a reference to theory explaining how we expand squared terms inside of a sum? In particular I am confused about where n comes from (as I guess it comes from the summation term, but would prefer to know for certain, rather than guess).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ave:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i^2-2\mu y_i+\mu^2)=
$$
$$
=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2 -\sum_{i=1}^n2\mu y_i +\sum_{i=1}^n\mu^2=
\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2 -2\mu\sum_{i=1}^n y_i +n\mu^2
$$

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for your help! I didnt realize it was that straight forward (I was thinking in a completely different direction). And so, the sum of mu^2 just becomes nmu^2 because mu doesnt rely on i like yi does?

Comment: $\mu$ is a constant and so the sum of $n$ times $\mu^2$ is $n\mu^2$...

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for your help Emilio!

Comment: You are welcome! And do not forget to accept the answer if it is useful. :)